# In docker technology, what is "container format", and what is it used for to do?

Tags: docker, containers

The docker docs only said:

> Docker Engine combines the namespaces, control groups, and UnionFS into a wrapper called a container format. The default container format is libcontainer. In the future, Docker may support other container formats by integrating with technologies such as BSD Jails or Solaris Zones.

But I still can not get what is really "container format".

Can someone give me more detailed information about "container format"？And what can I do with "container format"?

Thanks.

Comment: You can save pictures in various *image formats*, like JPEG, PNG, GIF etc. Container formats are the same thing for Docker containers.

Answer (score 0):

Docker as an application need to manipulate namespaces, control groups, capabilities, apparmor profiles, network interfaces and firewalling rules etc. to realize the functions.

Libcontainer is a pure Go library which developed to access the kernel’s container APIs directly, without any other dependencies, it's the default container format of docker.

So, I guess it's a low-level technology for docker, but as a final user, I guess we will not directly use it.

A [good article](https://blog.docker.com/2014/03/docker-0-9-introducing-execution-drivers-and-libcontainer/) for your reference, in it, you can see other container format as well.